# javac Package not found

Tags: java, import, package

I'm making a simple Java program without any IDE and I'm unable to call a class inside a package from another class.
This is my directory structure:

```
test/
  |_ B.java
  |_ pack/
       |_ A.java
       |_ A.class
```

What i want to do is to call A.java from B.java.

My A.java is a simple file:

```
package pack;
public class A{
    public void msg(){
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

I compiled A.java inside `test/`using `javac -d . pack/A.java` and it compiled without any problem.

B.java:

```
import pack.A;
class B{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        A obj = new A();
        obj.msg();
    }
}
```

I'm on Linux in the `test/` directory and when I compile, using `javac -d . B.java`, the compiler shows me some errors, and the most important one is:

```
B.java:1: error: package pack does not exist
import pack.A;
           ^
```

All other errors are a consequence of this one.
I've tried to change directories but nothing worked so far and I've done some research but I found nothing.
Can someone help me please?

Comment: Make sure that you include the right directory in the classpath, for example: `javac -cp . -d . B.java`

Comment: @Jesper isn't `.` part of the classpath by default, if it's not been overwritten somehow?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca that's default indeed, if you don't set the `CLASSPATH` environment variable (or override it another way).

Comment: @Jasper it worked, but when I execute B.java, using 'java B.java' , error persists; there is an option like -cp for the execution?
The CLASSPATH I used is not the default one, i changed it because of tomcat, I felt that the problem was something related to this damn thing

Comment: To execute it, don't specify the `.java` extension; just the class name: `java -cp . B`

Comment: @Jasper thank you very much, it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown by @Jasper the problem was the CLASSPATH variable which was not the default one.
The solution is to change the CLASSPATH or to specify the path while compiling/executing; this could be done compiling with `javac -cp . -d . B.java` and executing with `java -cp . B`